# 3D interpolation in Python Pandas using a mesh grid

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following 10 lines of a large Pandas dataframe df;

X,Y,Z are grid points in xyz-direction; U,V,W are (measured) velocity components in x,y,z-direction.

```
     X      Y      Z        U       V         W
0  -201.0  -2.00   11.200   3.750  -15.20  -0.75800
1  -201.0  -2.00   12.220   3.640  -15.40  -0.71100
2  -200.0  -3.00   1.079   -1.480   -3.86   0.03670
3  -198.0  -3.00   7.190   4.220   -13.50  -1.31000
4  -198.0  -1.43   5.530   3.510   -10.10  -1.56000
5  -195.0  -1.43   6.140   3.900   -11.80  -1.50000
6  -195.0  -2.54   0.000  -0.767   -5.19   0.00154
7  -195.0  -3.54   0.600  -1.210   -6.04   -0.05580
8  -191.0  -5.54   1.449  -1.510   -2.80   -0.20900
9  -191.0  -7.54   2.392  -0.782   -2.65   -0.56000
```

I want to now interpolate the values U,V,W over a finer 5x5x5 grid in X,Y,Z.

```
x = np.arange(-200, -175, 5)
y = np.arange(-10, 5, 5)
z = np.arange(0,20,5)
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x, y,z )
NT = np.product(xx.shape)
data_grid = {
    "x_grid": np.reshape(xx,NT),
    "y_grid": np.reshape(yy,NT),
    "z_grid": np.reshape(zz,NT)
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= data_grid)
```

I see scipy has this interpolate griddata function which I am trying to call (for now I only interpolate U in XYZ).

```
xp = df['X'].to_numpy()
yp = df['Y'].to_numpy()
zp = df['Z'].to_numpy()
up = df['U'].to_numpy()

U_grid = griddata([(xp,yp,zp)], up, [(x_grid,y_grid,z_grid)], method='nearest')
```

But this gives me:
"ValueError: different number of values and points"

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Be careful with the words "interpolation" and "averages values".

Comment: You are right, I did change it now.

Comment: In `griddata(points, values, ..)`, number of `points` and `values` must be equal.